# What does "that" in "you do that again" mean?

Tags: bloodshot-2020

KT disables Dr Emil's virtual simulation on Bloodshot:

> Dr Emil: The truth is, nobody wants to make real decisions anymore.
> They just wanna feel like they have. Goodbye, KT.
>
> KT: Like I would let you do **that** again.

Comment: This might be better placed at http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rendition of the quote on [this page](https://www.moviequotesandmore.com/bloodshot-best-quotes/) gives more context:

> **Dr. Emil Harting**: Why are you doing this?
> **KT**: Because he deserves the truth.
> **Dr. Emil Harting**: The truth is, nobody wants to make real decisions anymore.
> [he uses his bionic arm to throw her against the wall]
> **Dr. Emil Harting**: They just want to feel like they have. Goodbye, KT.
> [he goes to deactivate her breathing implant]
> **KT**: Like I would let you do that again.
> [he looks at his arm to see access has been denied to her breathing implant]

So, in this case, "that" is disabling her breathing implant to stop her from fighting him.

Comment: I don't have access to a shooting script to see if it matches up with the site.

Comment: That is exactly what happens and the context.